# Is there a persistence engine that can handle complex user-partitioned data for .Net?

Tags: .net, orm, persistence

Let's say I have this model:

```
  class Teacher
  {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
  }

  class Student
  {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
  }
```

And through some algorithm a user can only see a subset of Teachers and Students, for this example I can only see Teachers and Students that have a name that starts with the same letter as mine. So I want something like:

```
var myViewableTeachers = persistenceStore.Teachers();
```

which would return for example "Joyce", Jonas" and "Juja" but NOT "Steve", "Bill" or "Zaphod"

Now suppose that Teacher "Joyce" has a collection of Students named "Arnold", "Beverly", "Jolene", "Jerome" and "Zach".

Is there a persistence engine or OR/M that will make sure that when I access the Students of Joyce it will only return "Jolene" and "Jerome" for me and "Arnold" for a user named "Annabelle"?

- I want this in the entire storage engine, so if I later create a Classroom object with Students and Teachers I want those collections to only show accessible Teachers and Students.
- The algorithm to determine what is accessible can be pretty complex and be dependent on other data in storage.
- SQL, noSQL or other options are ok.

Comment: You say: "And through some algorithm a **user** can only see a subset of Teachers and Students". What is a user in this case? A person that logs into your program with a user name and password?

Comment: Correct. But I can imagine that other scenarios are also possible.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, that's not the job of the persistence engine / ORM. The job of the ORM is mapping the relational world to the object oriented world, i.e. it maps from your database to your object.

You can do this in two very different ways:

1. Create a view for each table that needs to be filtered like this. Map your objects in the ORM not to the tables but to the views. When initializing the database session, somehow make the current user known to the database.
2. Perform the filtering in your application as part of the business logic.

I would go with option 2 unless it would result in a lot of unnecessary data to be transmitted.

Comment: I understand but with a lot of relations in my current app I'm looking for a method to simplify this.